# DAX table calculations powerBI multiple column values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to select multiple cities from my dataset and create a subset with these cities, but some cities have the same name when they are in different states. For this reason, I only want to select the Boston from Massachusetts. For this I created the following query, but it seems to be giving me some errors. How do I fix this?

```
10_least_weather = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        Weather_records
       ,AND(
           Weather_records[City] 
               IN {"New York"
                  ,"Gilbert"
                  ,"Las Vegas"
                  ,"Huntington Beach"
                  ,"Boston"
                  ,"Paterson"
                  ,"Naperville"
                  ,"Cedar Rapids"
                  ,"Arvada"
                  ,"Santa Clarita"
                 }
              ,Weather_records[State] 
                   IN {"MI", "SC", "IL", "PA", "FL", "PA", "SC"}
         )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
FILTER(
    Weather_records
    ,SWITCH(
        TRUE()
        ,[State]="State1" && [City]="CityName1",TRUE()
        ,[State]="State2" && [City]="CityName2",TRUE()
        ,[State]="State3" && [City] IN {"CityName31","CityName32","CityName33"},TRUE()
        ,[State]="State4" && NOT [City] IN {"CityName41","CityName42"},TRUE()
       ...
        ,FALSE()
    )
```